What effects could cause a laser beam inside a pipe to bend?
I am seeing a deflection in a 450nm laser beam while it is being directed through 40ft of a 48"dia. fiberglass pipe (other pipe material (ie.- concrete) doesn't affect it).  Why?
FACT:  Heat waves in the pipe affect the beam, but the result is that the beam (dot) that is emitted onto the target simply vibrates randomly from a center point and it always returns to center once the heat has been evacuated from the pipe (using fans).
Could refraction be a factor since the pipe is made out of fiberglass (which is the same thing that fiber optics are made from)?
Could static electricity on the fiberglass pipe affect the laser beam?
I just don't see any of these variables as the culprit of the deviated beam.
There isn't any way an EMF could affect the Frequency of the 450nm laser beam (or is there)?

I've upvoted because it's an interesting question and mostly well-put, but I think you should describe your experiment a bit more, because, as others have pointed out, maybe there is refraction because of temperature gradient(s) in the lasers path or deflection of the measuring instruments.

Thank You all for your input!  What an amazing community this is!  No matter (almost) how ridiculous the question may originally seem, I thank you for considering the factors that I have provided.  I like the idea of trying this at night when most temperature factors have settled.  THANK YOU ALL!!!  You are AWESOME!

Laser beams are not bent by having fiberglass nearby, any more than they are bent by having ordinary glass nearby. Of course, a beam actually passing through glass will bend as it enters or exits the glass, or when it encounters changes in the density or composition of the glass. But just having glass, fibrous or otherwise, in the general vicinity, does not do it.
Light is also not bent by electric fields.
As you said, a temperature gradient in the air through which the beam is passing could bend the beam. Similarly, a gradient in the composition of the air could affect the beam. These light-bending effects occurring in the pipe would be clearly visible by eye as a distortion.
If you cannot see any distortion with your own eyes, then you should assume the measuring equipment, rather than the light, has been deflected. For example, if the measuring equipment is attached to the pipe, then perhaps you have discovered that the pipe has changed slightly in shape. Measuring equipment could be physically moved or otherwise affected by many other things, like static electricity, the weight of the pipe causing other surfaces to flex, and so on.

Refraction
If the air in the pipe is colder on one side than the other and convection isn't completely mixing hot with cold. Quite plausible if the pipe is positioned in the sun lying on cold(er) ground.
Otherwise it's more than likely that the pipe is slightly bent. You don't think of glass as flexible, until you have handled glass-blowing supplies (metre-long lengths of glass pipe).

If:

there was no air in the pipe
the 450 nm laser beam had a typical Gaussian-like shape (as opposed to a Bessel beam which would be absurd in this case)
with a diameter way smaller than the dielectric tube (say 1 mm vs. 1200 mm)

then there's no significant overlap of the laser's electric field with the dielectric material. In this case, you treat the laser beam as the definition of a straight line (for your purposes) and any deviations are purely the pipe's fault.
However as you point out, there is air in there, and the temperature affects density, so a temperature gradient can indeed refract the light a little bit. And the longer the pipe, the greater the deflection. In fact the deflection will scale as the square of the length assuming the gradient is the same everywhere.

If there is turbulence, then the density variations can be dynamic (the spot wiggles).
If the air is calm, then as @nigel222 points out you could have a static density gradient and your air will steadily bend the light towards the colder air side. (colder = higher density = higher index of refraction = slower speed)

How can I test this explanation?
Do the test different times of the day/night cycle (if that's the source of a temperature gradient), see if that makes a difference.
Also, get some big fans and blow the air around so that it mixes, and see if that gets rid of the static deflection you think you see.
